# Authorize.net direct post failing with hash

Tags: magento-1.9, authorize.net

I have a Magento 1.9 CE installation that was recently upgraded from 1.7.  Authorize.net direct post worked in 1.7, but now it does not work. When I try to checkout, I get the standard message about "Response hash validation failed. Transaction declined."

I made a new hash key and entered it in both Magento and authorize.net.  I then cleared the Magento cache.  I still get this error though.  I rebooted the server.  I tried a different browser.  Any thing I am missing?

Comment: One difference between 1.7 and 1.9 was the inclusion of a tax rule. I noticed over on this thread (http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4001/authorize-net-direct-post-hash-validation-failed) towards the end, person mentions that if submitted value is different, it can throw this error.  I have been noticing with the tax rule, before a user logs in, or an address is selected, tax is calculated and shows up in the subtotal.  So I deleted my tax rule, but it did not seem to have any impact.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs in the function `Mage_Authorizenet_Model_Directpost::validateResponse`. What this code does is checks for a trans_md5 and login set in the config and then validates them against the response.

```
public function validateResponse()
{
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    //md5 check
    if (!$this->getConfigData('trans_md5') || !$this->getConfigData('login') ||
        !$response->isValidHash($this->getConfigData('trans_md5'), $this->getConfigData('login'))
    ) {
        Mage::throwException(
            Mage::helper('authorizenet')->__('Response hash validation failed. Transaction declined.')
        );
    }
    return true;
}
```

What I would suggest is to step through this function and see what data causes the error.