# magento2.2.3 Authorize.net direct post response hash validation failed

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.2.3, authorize.net

I've set up **`authorize.net`** direct post in **test mode** on my live *server*.

Trying to make a purchase I get an error.  In the exception log I get :

> main.CRITICAL: The transaction was declined because the response hash
>   validation failed. {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(code: 0): The
>   transaction was declined because the response hash validation failed.
>   at
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-authorizenet/Model/Directpost.php:539)"}
>   []

Does anyone know why this is occurring?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please check this configuration in Magento and Authorize.net https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/4314/39238

Comment: @NalinSavaliya i am using magento2.2.3

Comment: Yes, I know. But it's same thing for Magento 2 configuration, just path is different

Comment: Please find below answer

Comment: Have you apply patch?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that payment/authorizenet_directpost/trans_md5 configuration was NULL.

To fix this set an MD5-Hash in the Authorize.net merchant admin under `Settings > Security Settings > General Security Settings > MD5-Hash`.

Then enter that same value in the Magento Admin under `Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods > Authorize.net Direct Post > Merchant MD5`.

Comment: here allready added : https://prnt.sc/qien1y

Answer (score 0):

Authorize.net will stop supporting MD5 based hash usage on June 28, 2019. This will result in Magento merchants not being able to process payments using Authorize.Net Direct Post. To avoid this, merchants need to apply the patch provided by Magento and replace the existing MD5 hash with a Signature Key (SHA-512) in the Magento Admin configuration settings.

You can find more details at https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024368392-Update-Authorize-Net-Direct-Post-from-MD5-to-SHA-512

Answer (score 0):

### 1º Method

You can upgrade to version 2.2.8 or 2.3.1

### 2º Method

You can apply this patch from Magento below. Don't copy the space in that your Authorize.net panel will show.

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024368392-Update-Authorize-Net-Direct-Post-from-MD5-to-SHA-512

[image: Magento 2 Authorize.net MD5 Hash]

Other solutions

- https://github.com/MeetanshiInc/Magento-Authorize-Net-Direct-Post-Patch-for-M1-M2/
- https://gist.github.com/robolmos/7a3bf336516b18f8e0bd48a13d93e1ef